# Empty class method implementation

Tags: c++, class, methods

I define a class Example with some data member ,setter and getter methods:

```
class Example
{
     private:
        int  variable_A;

     public:
        void set_A_value(int input)
        {
            variable_A = input;
        }
        int get_A_value()
        {
            return variable_A;
        }
}
```

Later, i create class instances and call the setter and getter method in other source code file.

If I decide to remove the variable_A from class Example afterwards, is it a good practice to leave the implementation for the getter and setter method empty, so that we dont have to remove the codes from other source file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell because you haven't provided any context, but I'm guessing you're doing something that isn't good object-oriented design.

Getters and setters should access *conceptual properties* of the class, not its *physical members*. If you make a getter and a setter for every private variable then it defeats the entire purpose of encapsulation.

Either `variable_A` stores a conceptual property of each object---in which case removing it would actually change the class's semantics (in which case code depending on it will have to be rewritten no matter what)---or it doesn't, but forms a part of a larger feature that can be rewritten in a way that does not involve `variable_A`---in which case there shouldn't be a getter and setter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping unused variables in the codes is not a good practice. It may create confusion to the readers. However, if the variable or the function are being used somewhere, removing them would definitely give error. And if they are not used, then you can give minimum priority to this work.